# At what point is someone considered תורתו אומנתו?

Tags: torah-study, talmidei-chakhamim

There is a Halachic category called תורתו אומנתו, which means that Torah is your profession.

At what point is someone considered to be at this level?

Is it a qualitative or quantitative count?

How many hours a day would it be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 106:11-12**

> ודע שדברי הרמב״ם בענין זה תמוהים מאד שכתב בפ״ו דין ח׳ מי שהיה עוסק בת״ת והגיע זמן התפלה פוסק ומתפלל ואם היתה תורתו אומנתו ואינו עושה מלאכה כלל והיה עוסק בתורה בשעת תפלתו אינו פוסק שמצות ת״ת גדולה ממצות תפלה עכ״ל והוא תימא שהרי בגמרא אמר ר׳ יוחנן לא שנו אלא כגון רשב״י וחביריו אבל אנו מפסיקין וכו׳ וכמ״ש הטור וש״ע וכיון דר׳ יוחנן הפסיק כ״ש אנחנו ור״י פשיטא שהיתה תורתו אומנתו ואיך כתב דמי שתורתו אומנתו אינו פוסק האם אנחנו גדולים מר״י וצע״ג
>
> ונראה שהרמב״ם מפרש מה שאמר כגון רשב״י וחביריו לא מיירי מצד גודל מעלתם ושקידתם אלא מפני שלא עשו שום מלאכה להתפרנס וכיון שאינו מפסיק לפרנסה אינו מפסיק גם לתפלה אבל שארי תנאים ואמוראים היה להם איזה פרנסה כמפורסם בש״ס ולכן מפסיקין ולפ״ז גם האידנא מי שאין לו שום מלאכה ג״כ לא יפסיק
>
> Know that the words of the Rambam on this topic are very bewildering. For in Chapter 6 Law 8 he writes that one who is engaged in Torah study and the time for prayer arrives should stop and pray, but if Torah is his trade and he does no work at all and he would engage in Torah at the time of his prayer then he should not stop, since the commandment of Torah study is greater then the commandment of prayer, end quote. And this is bewildering because in the Talmud R. Yochanan said that this was taught only for the likes of R. Shimon Bar Yochai, whereas we do stop etc. and as is written in the Tur and Shulchan Aruch. And since R. Yochanan stopped, certainly we [should stop]. Yet R. Yochanan was obviously “Torah is his trade”, so how could he write that one whose trade is Torah should not stop? Are we greater than R. Yochanan? And this requires much analysis.
>
> And it seems that the Rambam explains [that] that which he says “like R. Shimon Bar Yochai and his colleagues” is not dealing with the greatness of their level or their diligence, but because they did not do any work to be supported. And since they don’t stop for livelihood they also don’t stop for prayer. Whereas the rest of the tannaim and amoraim had some sort of livelihood as is publicized in the Talmud, and therefore they stopped. And according to this even nowadays one who has no work whatsoever would also not stop.

Answer (score 2):

The Rosh Bava Basra 1:27 says as follows

ונראה שת"ח שיש לו אומנות או קצת משא ומתן להתפרנס כדי חייו ולא להתעשר ובכל שעה שהוא פנוי מעסקו מחזר על דברי תורה
לומד דברי תורה הוא הנקרא תורתו אומנותו

*It would seem that a Talmid Chochom who has a profession or small business to support himself in  a minimal manner and not to become wealthy and anytime he is free from work he returns to learning Torah, that is what is called  תורתו אומנותו*

Note: The Rosh is  saying that *even* someone who has a small side business can be  considered Torosoy Umnosoy. Not that it is a a requirement.

Comment: yes, this is lshitaso in brachos on the sugya of birchas hatorah. thank you very much.